# its not going to adforest_checkout after a successful payment,how to fix this ? and also suggest me a way to multiply amout(string) with 100

Tags: java, android, android-studio, razorpay

Razorpay payment gateway with adforest(codecanyone) checkout(Success)

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String razorpayPaymentID) {
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
            adforest_Checkout();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in onPaymentSuccess", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`?

Comment: @stark I think because he does not use his variable 'razorpayPaymentID' from the method signature. who is adforest_Checkout()? please provide more code or context to this usse

Comment: I cant add it here cause it shows the error (mostly code...)

Comment: https://github.com/SahalCk/PaymentIssue

Comment: Here is its github link.. please have a look and help me

Comment: And adforest is paid android source code by codecanyon

Comment: @Emerson micu ..